# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one activity calling another. But it keeps giving me the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference".

Calling activity:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent (this, buisnessProfileEdit.class);
Bundle data1 = new Bundle();
data1.putString("Restaurant Username",restaurantUsername);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Called activity:

```
Intent intentReceived = getIntent();      
Bundle data = intentReceived.getExtras();
restaurantUsername = data.getString("Restaurant Username");
```

Can someone help me out why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The problem is it says my restaurantUsername is a null pointer. But I don't know why it is and how to fix it. I defined String restaurantUsername="" on top.

Comment: `I defined String restaurantUsername="" on top` ... of **which** Activity?

Comment: On the called activity.

Comment: In both classes it is both defined.

Comment: add this line intent1.putExtras(data1) before startActivity, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the extras to the actual Intent:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent (this, buisnessProfileEdit.class);
Bundle data1 = new Bundle();
data1.putString("Restaurant Username",restaurantUsername);
intent1.putExtras(data1);
startActivity(intent1);
```

(PS: you have a typo in buisnessProfileEdit.)

Answer (score 4):

#### The real problem is that you are missing to pass the bundle via intent:

```
intent1.putExtras(data1);
```

try this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent (this, buisnessProfileEdit.class);
Bundle data1 = new Bundle();
data1.putString("Restaurant Username",restaurantUsername);
intent1.putExtras(data1);
startActivity(intent1);
```

even you will add a validation for this in your Called activity:

```
Intent intentReceived = getIntent();      
Bundle data = intentReceived.getExtras();
if(data != null){
     restaurantUsername = data.getString("Restaurant Username");
}else{
     restaurantUsername = "";
}
```

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

You can´t invoke the method `getString()` because your bundle is null!

Answer (score 4):

Another much simpler and less verbose option is to add and get the extras from the intent itself.

In the calling activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, CalledActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("FOO", foo);
```

In the called activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String foo = extras.getString("FOO");
```